# How to use chrome driver with head in Scrapy Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I Am using Scrapy with scrapySelenium but the scrapy selenium starts with a headless browser but for some purpose i need to start it with head so i can keep seeing what my scrapy does in the browser how to turn off headless arguments passed in settings of scrapy

this is what i copied in the settings it is headless as you can see but want to see the browser open up with Scrapy Selenium is there anyway
from shutil import which

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headles']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS = ['--headless']` from the settings.py.

With selenium webdriver you can pass arguments and this argument makes sure that it is a headless browser.

Comment: Could you click the tick on the left hand side of my post to make it the accepted answer? Thanks